# Как легко написать ввод данных?

Tags: c

Здравствуйте!

Есть задача: [вот](http://inf.reshuege.ru/problem?id=7216).
Мне всё понятно, кроме 1 вещи с точки зрения синтаксиса.
Как легко организовать ввод данных?
Вариант с пробелами не интересен, а шерстить всю строку нельзя.

Пишу на Си(без плюсов).

**PS** Пол года не писал, честно говоря много забыл.

Comment: если Вы полгода не писали и забыли, значит Вы не знали.

Comment: Ваш код скорее всего не будет работать - либо покажите структуру, либо, добавьте как минимум два `&`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

scanf и аналоги. Первых заходом читаете N, потом в цикле по 4 поля

```
int n, class, ball;
char fam[21];
char name[16];

scanf("%d", &n);
for (int i = 0; i< n; i++) {
   scanf("%20s %15s %d %d", fam, name, &class, &bal);
   // обрабатываем данные
}
```

Comment: @KoVadim, извините за хамство, но представленный Вами код я могу написать и сам. В критериях указанно, что использование массива не рационально, но указывают требования, что "<класс> — число от 7 до 11", т.е. после каждого ввода их нужно проверять и либо принимать, либо нет. Я знаю, только если написать кучу if else после каждого ввода, но это глупо. Поэтому и задал вопрос, о таком специфичном требовании!

Comment: @ВладиславМСК, проверяйте. 

Все, что считаете нужным, обязательно проверяйте. Обязательно пишите хорошую диагностику (например, в Вашем случае какая ошибка в данных и *в какой строке*) и корректно восстанавливайтесь при ошибках. Можете даже ловить SIGHUP и SIGTERM и писать о неожиданной остановке в лог.

--

Только не ждите, что кто-то за Вас будет писать здесь весь этот промышленный код.

Или вопросы соответствующим образом формулируйте.

Comment: @ВладиславМСК а Вы решили, что `char fam[21];` - это использование массивов? да, это массив, но это строка. Без массива тут сложно решить. (можно выделить память через malloc, но это тот же массив).

if - else писать не глупо, если правильно. Что бы проверить на класс, нужен всего то один if

    if (class < 7 || class > 11) continue;

Comment: @KoVadim, я не говоил о массиве char, а о том, что если создать массив для хранения всех данных - то за это снизят балл. Просто я уже запутался, если делаешь все красиво и сохраняешь - это неиоптимально, и за задачу дают 2 из 4, а если применять некрасивые способы, то это хорошо, но не всегда понятно.

Comment: Для указанной задачи не нужны промежуточные массивы. Читаете, анализируете, если балы больше 200 - печатаете. Также запоминаете максимального. Всех делов.

Хватит ныть!

Answer (score 2):

В чем проблема? Берите структуру для ученика и вперед.

UPD: с подсказки [[@KoVadim](/users/2739/kovadim)](/users/2739/kovadim), что бы все по феншую:

```
struct listNode{
    char name[20];
    char fname[15];
    int classX;
    int points;
} node;

...

FILE *fp = fopen("text.txt","r");
fscanf(fp, "%s %s %d %d,", node.name, node.fname, &node.classX, &node.points);
```

Comment: В Вашем решении есть ошибка. цитирую часть условия

>  <класс> — число от 7 до 11

Comment: @KoVadim, мда... надо больше высыпаться, что бы таких ошибок не было. Еще раз спасибо за подсказки.